# Append footer only once within a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, shopify

My code is a bit complex as I'm appending dynamic content to a cart following a successful AJAX call. I need to add the footer ($(.mini-cart__footer)) to the cart only once at the end of the li items. How do I achieve that? The problem I'm currently facing that every time a li is added, a footer section is attached to it - so if 3 products are added to the cart, I'll end up with 3 footer sections.

Here is my code:

```
var __isp_options = {
  isp_add_to_cart_callback: function(product_id) {
      var image = ISP_PRODUCTS[product_id].image.replace('?c=2', '');
      var title = ISP_PRODUCTS[product_id].l;
      var description = ISP_PRODUCTS[product_id].d;
      var price = ISP_PRODUCTS[product_id].p;

      isp_add_to_cart(event, product_id);


      var miniCart_html = '<div class="mini-cart__full is-mini-cart"><ul class="mini-cart__items is-cart__items"><li class="mini-cart__item"><div class="mini-cart__image-container"><a href="#" class="mini-cart__remove icon-cross-container" data-action="remove-product"><svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use></svg></a><img class="mini-cart__image" src="'+image+'"></div><div class="product-meta"><span class="cart-item__brand">'+title+'</span><h2 class="product-meta__title">'+'1 X '+'<span class="product-meta__title cart-item__title product-tag">'+description+'<span class="dot"></span><span class="dot"></span></span></h2><span class="product-meta__price" data-money-convertible="">'+Shopify.formatMoney(price)+'</span></div></li></ul></div>';

      $('.mini-cart__content').append(miniCart_html);

      $('.is-cart__items').append('<footer class="mini-cart__footer"><div class="mini-cart__total"><span class="mini-cart__total-label">'+'Total'+'</span><span class="mini-cart__total-price" data-money-convertible="">'+Shopify.formatMoney(price)+'</span></div><form action="/cart" method="POST"><a href="/cart" class="button button--full button--primary">'+'Continue to checkout'+'</a></form></footer>')
  }
}

function isp_add_to_cart(event, product_id) {

  $.ajax({
    url: '/cart?view=mini-cart-content/add?id='+ product_id + "&quantity=1",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log('success');
  $.getJSON('/cart.js').then(function(results) {
    if (results['item_count'] > 0) {
      $('.cart-icon-wrapper__count').text(results['item_count']);
      $('.cart-icon-wrapper--has-items').show();
      $('.cart-icon-wrapper--empty').hide();
    }
  });
    },
    error: function(result) { console.log('error'); }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What if you add the footer from the start just make it hidden and when you add an "li" element, just make it visible. In this case it will not be a problem if you just make it visible several times.

Comment: It seems to me, that your code is incomplete. I don't see usage of `__isp_options` variable. Also, try to isolate your problem and post here only code which causes the issue, without any additional `show/hide` methods.

Comment: @dganenco the code has to be wrapped in the __isp_options in order to work. It's an InstantSearch+ plugin/Shopify integration.

Comment: ok...but how then is your $ajax call connected to the usage of it? It's not clear. The AJAX call fires, the response comes back, and you just log the response. How does that cause `isp_add_to_cart_callback` to be fired? But anyway, Alexey's solution seems to be the obvious one - make the footer permanent, but hide it until there is at least one item in the cart.

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin the problem is that the element I'm attaching the footer to is not part of the DOM before the callback - so I have no element to attach it.

Comment: "the element I'm attaching the footer to is not part of the DOM before the callback" ...the obvious solution to that is to make it part of the DOM, and hide it. Then just show the whole cart element once there is at least one item in the cart. Same idea, just on a different DOM element. It looks like you are appending a lot more than you need to each time you add a cart item..surely you only need to append a single `<li>` and its content? The rest can be static, I would have thought? Otherwise for each cart item you'll end up with a new list, each list containing one item, which is a bit silly

Comment: @ADyson thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: No problem. As a separate point, I notice you call `isp_add_to_cart(event, product_id);` but do not wait for the response before updating the screen with the added cart item. What if there's an error (e.g. due to server fault, or bad network connection, or something like that)? The user will believe the item is added to the cart, but the application will have no record of it, and the user is not aware that a problem occurred. This sounds like a recipe for confusion.

Comment: @Adyson, I'm dealing with that part now. Restructuring the code and will be running different code blocks for different scenarios e.g. item already in the cart, network issues etc. Thanks!